# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error using screenshot_as_png in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, png, screenshot, element

It gives this error for CSS that exist but do not appear in the site's interface.

My code (site and css are examples):

```
driver.get("www.example.com")
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("css").screenshot_as_png
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot take screenshot with 0 width."}
```

but if the link changes, ie tries to take a screenshot from a link where the bodies appear, it works correctly.

what i tried to do is continue without any error. because when it fails, the script stops.

**Solution**

After some research I found the solution.
CODE (site and css are examples):

```
driver.get("www.example.com")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css")))
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("css").screenshot_as_png
    print ("element visible")

except TimeoutException:
    print ("element not visible")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a property called**

```
WebElement.screenshot_as_png
```

**This returns png as binary data , if you want to store the image as file you can use .screenshot() method**

```
WebElement.screenshot("hi.png")
```

you can see all avaialble methods and properties of webelement at :

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html

**example:**

```
driver.find_element_by_id("anyid").screenshot_as_png

driver.find_element_by_id("anyid").screenshot("hi.png")
```

### As per the error the screenshot not working because of its width , see if the element is properly visible before you take screenshot

use webdriver wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

elem= wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'somelocator')))
```

Comment: yes i used something close to this and fixed it. Thank you so much. but what I want to do is take a screenshot of where the element is located. I save this later. So there is no problem right now.

Comment: @HengenAsdwdrasd this does taht you can use any locator

Comment: you can accept the answer by pressing the tikc sign if it helped

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute as `screenshot_as_png` for the [remote webdriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver) but the method is [get_screenshot_as_png()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_screenshot_as_png) which gets the screenshot of the current window as a binary data.

- Usage:

  ```
  driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
  ```

---

### Solution

Essentially `get_screenshot_as_png()` is a webdriver method and your effective code block will be:

```
element_screenshot_png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How can I take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver/55120087#55120087)

Comment: I don't want to take a full screenshot. Also my error seems to be related to the screenshot but it is not. thank you anyway. I solved the problem and will explain the solution soon.

Comment: thats incorrect statement , https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html , it has that property